# Installing numpy python

Tags: python, numpy, windows-7

I am trying to install numpy in my computer. I've installed numpy with pip, however, when I am tried to write import numpy in terminal I am receiving: `no module name numpy`. I have 64bit Windows 7 and AMD processor. Is there any conflict with AMD? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: what does help modules print?

Comment: No python documentation for python.

Comment: Do you have more than one Python installation?

Comment: How can I check this? I am not sure if I erased old version properly.

Comment: Basically I ve installed canopy. Is there a chance of having isuues due to canopy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had trouble with a similar issue when I was mismatching 64-bit and 32-bit python and modules.

I ended up getting Portable Python, which comes pre-installed with all the fun bits and is made for Windows: http://portablepython.com/

Not sure if it would work in your situation though.